# Setting process.env environment variables in Lambda wrapper script do not show up in Lambda handler

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to set environment variables from inside a Lambda wrapper script contained in a Lambda layer (I can do this more directly elsewhere, but I'm trying to set them from a wrapper script for specific scenarios).

Here's the important parts of the wrapper script:

```sh
set -euo pipefail

OWN_FILENAME="$(basename $0)"
tempFile=$(mktemp /tmp/${OWN_FILENAME}.XXXXXXXX)

echo "export ONE=\"two\"" >> ${tempFile}
. ${tempFile}
```

Here, I'm creating a temporary file which contains an environment variable exported to the environment. Then I source the file.

I would expect this to create a variable called `ONE` on `process.env`, which is set to `"two"`.

If I were to run this script and then run a Node script that contains:

```js
console.log(process.env.ONE);
```

It would print `"two"`.

However, this appears to not work with a NodeJS Lambda. I can see that, if I add logs to the wrapper script, the logs will print prior to the Lambda handler running, so it appears the wrapper script is definitely executing prior to the handler.

[AWS has a blog post here that shows the above process for setting environment variables. See the section "Conversion to environmental variables"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-aws-lambda-environmental-variables-from-aws-secrets-manager/).

Is there something I'm not doing to make this work for a Lambda handler?

Comment: I don't think this approach is going to work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66252692/finding-an-equivalent-of-environment-variables-in-aws-lambda-layers